# Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1 String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I added a new column (varchar) into an existing table and would like to replace the nulls with "P/R" in every single row of that column.

This can easily be done on Access database as "P/R" AS [column] but I cannot find the equivalent on SQL.

I have tried the code below and have received an error which doesn't make sense to me. Can someone please explain why and provide a solution?

Many Thanks,

```
Alter table [EPG 00) Premium] add [Earning] varchar

Update [EPG 00) Premium] 
set [earning] = 'P/R'
where [earning] is null
```

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
>   String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Comment: This is why you should **always** declare your length, scale, and precision. In  this case `Alter table [EPG 00) Premium] add [Earning] nvarchar` = `Alter table [EPG 00) Premium] add [Earning] nvarchar(1)`. `'P/R'` is 3 characters long, and therefore too large for your new column (by 2 characters).

Comment: Should be varchar(size), where size is the max number of characters.

Comment: On a different note, do you *really* have a table with the name `EPG 00) Premium`? You should really be avoiding any names that cause you to need your delimit identify your objects, and especially special characters like parentheses (`()`).

Comment: Hi Larnu, Thank you for all your help! I am transferring tables and queries from Access Database incl the odd table names but will take your advice on board! :)

Answer (score 2):

varchar default length 1 may be that's you got error

```
Alter table [EPG 00) Premium] add [Earning] varchar(10)

Update [EPG 00) Premium] 
set [earning] = 'P/R'
where [earning] is null
```